# new Elastic search client code for filter aggregation followed by nested aggregation and term aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Please help me to get new ElasticsearchClient equivalent code for below search criteria.

Need new java ElasticsearchClient code for filters followed by nested query and term query.

```
{
  "aggs_all_filters": {
    "filters": {
      "filters": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "adjust_pure_negative": true,
            "boost": 1.0
          }
        }
      ],
      "other_bucket": false,
      "other_bucket_key": "_other_"
    },
    "aggregations": {
      "facetsData": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "data.attributes.facetEnable.searchable"
        }       
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Currently no documentation avilable for same. You can refer this [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/issues/281).

Comment: I think we can solve above one if we know how to write subaggregations with new java client.. But I don't see any option to write sub aggregations with New ElasticSearchClient